# Where is the accumulate option in Brush Setting in sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting, settings, sculpt-mode

Does anybody know where the *Accumulate* option is for the *Grab Brush*? It is supposed to be in the *Brush* dropdown menu under use original but it isn't there on mine.

[image]

Comment: what brush have you selected?

Comment: The grab brush, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's available for the grab brush but for version 3.2.1 it's available for these brushes: *Draw*, *Draw* Sharp, *Clay*, *Clay* Strips, *Clay* Thumb, *Inflate*, *Blob*, *Crease*, *Flatten*, *Scrape*, *Rotate*, *Slide* and *Relax*.

Comment: no. i just checked version 3.2.1 for Grab Brush and it's not available there. Please post a screenshot to support your claim with the selected Grab brush :)

Comment: From my understanding, the grab brush doesn't work the same way as the other brushes so I don't think there is anything to accumulate. 
From the docs: "Used to drag a group of vertices around. Grab selects a group of vertices on mouse-down, and pulls them to follow the mouse. And unlike other brushes, Grab does not move different vertices as the brush is dragged across the model. The effect is like moving a group of vertices in Edit Mode with Proportional Editing enabled, except that Grab can make use of other Sculpt Mode options (like textures and symmetry)."